# How can i specify an order in mink/behat tests?

Tags: testing, behat, mink

I'm using mink/behat to test my website.
I need certain features be executed before others.
Is there a way to specify an order of execution?

For example:
There are 3 features: Administration, Login, Buy
I need to execute them in this order: Login, Administration, Buy

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Behat executes files in an alphabetic order. You could prefix them with a number to force the order.

However...

Scenarios are meant to be independent and the execution order shouldn't matter.

Comment: How would you then test very common use case of website that has to register user in order to use the same user in later tests?
I know I can put user in fixtures, but that also shouldn't be a point. Also registering him in beginning of every feature is overkill.

Comment: @slob that's a new question, so you should ideally post it as a new question. However, you can handle that with a beforeSuite function in your context or by having a mock user created as some other pre-testing step. There are more answers I'd give if you posted a question ;)

Comment: It "shouldn't" matter does not mean it "could" matter - and you will only find out if the case is that you do have dependencies unless you have good isolation of tests - or you regularly run in random order.  Preferably both.

Answer (score 0):

`behat` now allows you to specify an order from the existing `Orderer` implementations:

```bash
vendor/bin/behat --order=[random|reverse|null]
```

so for randon:

```bash
vendor/bin/behat --order=random
```

I believe you could also write your own.  If you wish to control the order in terms of batches, e.g. `set x` scenarios need to run before `set y` this could be achieved by just tags and running the two separate suites in sequence.